# C++ lvalue references

Tags: c++, reference, lvalue

So recently I revisited references on the type declaration but I didn't quite understand them.

Consider this dummy code:

```
int ia = 10;
int& ref = ia;
```

Now, my questions are:

1. how do these `int& ref` work internally, does it mean here that the address of `ref` is assigned the address of `ia` and thus equal to `&ia` if not then what does the compiler do upon seeing these references?
2. Why aren't these *references* compiled in a c++ program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ standard doesn't specify how reference should be implemented by the compiler. A lot of people think they are just aliases, but in fact, under the hood they are just implemented as `const` pointers.

C++ references are `const` pointers under the hood. So:

```cpp
int ia = 10;
int& ref = ia;
ref++; // ia is 11 now
```

might be converted by the compiler to:

```cpp
int ia = 10;
int* const ref = ia;
(*ref)++; // ia is 11 now
```

They need initialization because constants must be initialized.

Comment: This is false under most circumstances, see https://godbolt.org/z/TA8tkN for instance.

Comment: It's not false. Try with -00. and loose the `iostream` to get a clearer output. See: https://godbolt.org/z/xEQVXe   also, check this thread: https://twitter.com/tvaneerd/status/1252653227885178882?s=20

Comment: If you loose the ostream, the code is a noop, and O0 is more a reflection of the AST here, than the semantics of references.

Comment: `O0` is what the actual assembly is produced by the compiler in debug mode. Under different circumstances, the compiler may not be able to optimize this to a simple assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to think of addresses at all. `ref` is just another name for `ia`, or put another way, `ref` is an alias to `ia`. Just syntactic sugar for your code.

The compiler in this case doesn't have to do much at all, just keep track of when the code contains `ref`, replace it with `ia`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I would like to know how this works internally. What does the compiler do when it sees this?

Comment: @Alex • the C++ standard does not dictate what the compiler does internally.  My compiler eliminates the reference where possible, and treats it as if it were just an alias substitution for the object referred to.

Comment: @Eljay oh ok, didn't know that.

Comment: But then how do macro constants differ from references?

Comment: @Alex, macros are not treated by the compiler at all, but rather by the preprocessor.

Comment: @Alex • macros are just textual token substitutions, done by the C preprocessor.  They're not like macros in Lisp.

Comment: So, when should I use macros vs references?

Comment: @Alex, in general, you would avoid macros when ever possible.

Comment: @t.niese yeah I know, so in conclusion I should use references to just to be referring to a variable by another name?

Comment: @Alex, the processor uses the definition of the macro to perform a search an replace on your source code, the final result is then compiled (there are no macros in the compilation step). So if you have something like `#define MY_CONSTANT 2` and `int a = MY_CONSTANT;` then for the compiler it is just `int a = 2;`. And that's an example where you don't want to use macros because there are `const` and `constexpr` which fit such a usecase more. Nowadays the correct use of macros is limited to a few cases, you can often see them for creating unit tests.

Comment: @Alex You usually use them for more complex expressions or as function arguments.

Comment: @Alex This answer is incomplete and incorrect. You can *think* of references as aliases but that doesn't mean they are implemented as aliases. Under the hood they are just pointers.